# Add empty row to query results if no results found

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I'm writing stored procs that are being called by a legacy system. One of the constraints of the legacy system is that there must be at least one row in the single result set returned from the stored proc. The standard is to return a zero in the first column (yes, I know!).

The obvious way to achieve this is create a temp table, put the results into it, test for any rows in the temp table and either return the results from the temp table or the single empty result.

Another way might be to do an EXISTS against the same where clause that's in the main query before the main query is executed.

Neither of these are very satisfying. Can anyone think of a better way. I was thinking down the lines of a UNION kind of like this (I'm aware this doesn't work):

```
--create table #test
--(
--  id int identity,
--  category varchar(10)
--)
--go
--insert #test values ('A')
--insert #test values ('B')
--insert #test values ('C')

declare @category varchar(10)

set @category = 'D'

select
    id, category
from #test
where category = @category
union
select
    0, ''
from #test
where @@rowcount = 0
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's an old question, but i had the same problem.
Solution is really simple WITHOUT double select:

```
select top(1) WITH TIES * FROM (
select
id, category, 1 as orderdummy
from #test
where category = @category
union select 0, '', 2) ORDER BY orderdummy
```

by the "WITH TIES" you get ALL rows (all have a 1 as "orderdummy", so all are ties), or if there is no result, you get your defaultrow.

Comment: In case anyone is looking for the WITH TIES syntax that works in Oracle (tested in 19c):

`select * from ( your_query_here ) order by orderdummy fetch first 1 row with ties;`

Comment: This works from Oracle 12 onward.

Answer (score 37):

Very few options I'm afraid.

You always have to touch the table twice, whether COUNT, EXISTS before, EXISTs in UNION, TOP clause etc

```
select
    id, category
from mytable
where category = @category
union all --edit, of course it's quicker
select
    0, ''
where NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM mytable where category = @category)
```

An EXISTS solution is better then COUNT because it will stop when it finds a row. COUNT will traverse all rows to actually count them

Comment: If you have a long complex query that you do not want to repeat, you could do something like: `;WITH cte AS (...) ... SELECT * FROM cte UNION ALL SELECT 0, '' WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM cte)`

Answer (score 4):

You can use a full outer join. Something to the effect of ...

```
declare @category varchar(10)

set @category = 'D'

select #test.id, ISNULL(#test.category, @category) as category from (
    select
        id, category
    from #test
    where category = @category
)  
FULL OUTER JOIN (Select @category as CategoryHelper ) as EmptyHelper on 1=1
```

Currently performance testing this scenario myself so not sure on what kind of impact this would have but it will give you a blank row with Category populated.

Comment: That's a really interesting solution that avoids writing the where clause twice. I'd be interested in knowing whether this works and what the performance costs are? I can't work out why you wrap the main query in a derived table. Is this necessary?

Comment: The main query wrapping is due to the where clause but may be rewritten depending on how you are structuring the underlying query. It you dont join in the correct area (post-filtering), then the criteria is applicable to both tables. Costs appear to be minimal (0% in actual execution plan) however the query I have is fairly complex in its operation.

Answer (score 4):

This is @swe's answer, just reformatted:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [mail].[f_GetRecipients]
(
    @MailContentCode VARCHAR(50)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
    SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES -- Returns either all Priority 1 rows or, if none exist, all Priority 2 rows
        [To],
        CC,
        BCC
    FROM (
        SELECT
            [To],
            CC,
            BCC,
            1 AS Priority
        FROM mail.Recipients
        WHERE 1 = 1
            AND IsActive = 1
            AND MailContentCode = @MailContentCode

        UNION ALL

        SELECT
            *,
            2 AS Priority
        FROM (VALUES
            (N'system@company.com', NULL, NULL),
            (N'author@company.com', NULL, NULL)
        ) defaults([To], CC, BCC)
    ) emails
    ORDER BY Priority
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could try:

```
Declare @count int
set @count = 0

Begin
Select @count = Count([Column])
From //Your query

if(@Count = 0) 
   select 0
else //run your query
```

The downside is that you're effectively running your query twice, the up side is that you're skiping the temp table.

Comment: This is a similar method to the EXISTS statement I suggested in the question. The difference is the count is a little less efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Query for a dummy row and use a left join.

Say you have these queries:

```
mydb=> SELECT 1 AS a, 2 AS b;
 a | b 
---+---
 1 | 2
(1 row)

mydb=> SELECT 1 AS a, 2 AS b WHERE false;
 a | b 
---+---
(0 rows)
```

You always want 1 row.

You can use a left-join on a 1-row placeholder. This can be expressed as a join or a CTE.

```
mydb=> SELECT coalesce(q.a, 0) AS a, q.b
       FROM (VALUES (NULL)) AS dummy_row
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (
         SELECT 1 AS a, 2 AS b
       ) AS q ON (true);
 a | b 
---+---
 1 | 2
(1 row)

mydb=> SELECT coalesce(q.a, 0) AS a, q.b FROM
       (VALUES (NULL)) AS dummy_row
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (
         SELECT 1 AS a, 2 AS b WHERE false
       ) AS q ON (true);
 a | b 
---+---
 0 |  
(1 row)
```

that's the subquery formulation using `VALUES (NULL)` to provide the placeholder row. Here's a CTE based spelling with `generate_series` instead:

```
mydb=> WITH q AS (SELECT 1 AS a, 2 AS b WHERE false)
       SELECT coalesce(q.a, 0) AS a, q.b FROM generate_series(1,1) x left join q on (true);
 a | b 
---+---
 0 |  
(1 row)
```

Oops, postgres spelling, not MS-SQL. The same principle should apply. I'll fix it later.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid duplicating the selecting query, how about a temp table to store the query result first? And based on the temp table, return default row if the temp table is empty or return the temp when it has result?